# DownloadManager download completed but file stored two times. Why?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

- Hi everyone!
  This is my code. I want to download a file from a web server.
  The file is downloaded and stored, but in Downloads dir of Android Emulator device there are two files.

Why?

Can anyone help me please? *

```
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import java.io.File 

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var my_download_id : Long = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val text : TextView = findViewById(R.id.Text)
        val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.Button)

        button.setOnClickListener{

            val request = DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse("https://my3xample.org/file.csv"))
                .setTitle("FileExample")
                .setDescription("File Example Downloading")
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
                .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"Example.csv")

            val dm = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            my_download_id = dm.enqueue(request)

        }

        val br = object:BroadcastReceiver(){
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                val id = intent?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
                if(id == my_download_id){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Example File Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

        }

        registerReceiver(br, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
    }

}
```

This is the Downloads Dir when I download the file.

[Downloads Dir Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77gjH.png)

Comment: Which one is the right file? You saw the second one has 0 bytes? Further: i have more files in Download then you! ;-) So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: If you download the file yet one time then how many files in download dir then?

Comment: Exactly, the second file has 0 bytes. The right file is the first. ( on the left ). Why it shows the file on the right? What is that?

Comment: The right file should have the name "Example.csv'. so why are you telling that the left one is ok?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's not okay but I think that on the left side there is the correct file. The problem is that I don't understand why. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you got any solution to the same?